# Importing a global css file in Angular causes Webpack to emit huge module bundles

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass

We're using a bunch of global styles and imports in our angular-cli-generated Angular application, defined in `styles.scss` (the file starts with `/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */` if that seems familiar).

However, when this line is added to the top of the file:

```
@import '~@company/company-wide-styles'
```

the webpack builds produce bundles that are megabytes in size. The import refers to a 1120 lines long css file (compiled, unminified).

It might be relevant that we have ejected the configuration since we will need to customize some settings shortly that angular-cli didn't support yet. The ejects were performed with the following commands:

```
ng eject --aot -e dev -dev

ng eject --aot -e prod -prod
```

and the config files were then used in the respective builds.

What could be causing these huge file sizes? With the import line the files generated in the build are at least **doubled in size**!

The company wide styles are downloaded with yarn from a local registry set up with artifactory, but they sit happily in node_modules just like any other package, so I don't think that's relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out we had a lot of unnecessary imports in our scss files. In almost every single file, the entirety of the global `styles.scss` was imported. I can only conclude that this led to massive code duplication across the app.

Replacing the imports of the big global file with more specific files (for variables and mixins) reduced the bundles to a normal size.